# Why does the background of TextView change it's size?

Tags: android, layout, textview

I put a background to a TextView. I expect the background will adjust to my existing layout parameters and will not change the size of my TextView. So if I have width and height set to wrap_content, I would expect the background also wraps content (and scales down). But no, what I get is a bigger TextView

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/large_bg"
/>
```

I get

[image]

...

How do I make that the background also obeys wrap_content?

I mean, this looks like the background would be treated as content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when we set background than textView or any Widget adjusts itself according to that background.Until and Unless we have not mentioned the Fix Height and Width[Its Poor approach]

Comment: Does that make sense? A background is just a background and should adjust to the content, in this case, the text.

Comment: Ye4s this is the way android works,,,even if u will give this background to button then you will see that button will be of this size...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I expect a bit more deep answer for the "why" to select...